# How to do a javascript redirection to a ClickOnce deployment URL?

Tags: javascript, security, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application used to view some documents on a website. When connected, the user sees a list of documents as links to http://server/myapp.application?document=*docname*.
It worked fine until I had to integrate the website authentication/security system into my application.
The website uses a ticketing system to grant access to its users. A ticket is generated by a web application and needs to be added to the deployment URL querystring, then I have to check at application startup that the ticket given in querystring was right by making another request to the web application. So the deployment URL becomes something like: http://server/myapp.application?document=*docname*&ticket=*ticketnumber*.
The problem is the ticket is valid only 10 seconds, so I have to get it only after the user has clicked a link. My first try was to have some javascript do the request to get the ticket, generate the proper deployment URL and then redirect the user to this URL with "window.location = deploymentUrl;".

It works fine in Firefox, but IE does not prompt the user for installation. I guess it is a ClickOnce security constraints, but I am able to do the redirection when doing it on localhost, so I hope there is a workaround. I have also added the server on the "trusted sites" list in IE options.

Is it possible to have that working in IE? What are my other options to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work. ClickOnce doesn't support redirection; it has to have a straight shot from the client to the server to pick up the application and its updates.

RobinDotNet